# How can I change the default applications menu theme- Freya?

Tags: release-freya, themes

I want to change the classic view of applications menu with nice looking one. Here is the default screenshot. I want to replace this with new one.

[image]

Comment: What do you want to change? You can change the colors with an GTK theme. You can replace the launcher itself with a DConf setting.

Comment: can we make it look like windows starter menu?.  and if any possiblity to change the `applications` word to `icon`.

Comment: I don't think you can customize it that far. I'm not even sure you can use an image instead of text. If you really want an Windows Experience you might be better of using an distro that comes closer to it (Linux Mint or Zorin OS). Or you could try elementary OS as it is (which I recommend).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you the Arc theme: https://github.com/horst3180/Arc-theme

Arc theme for Firefox: https://github.com/horst3180/arc-firefox-theme

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is ok for now.  Thanks for your answer